# Is this a sensible password usage scheme?

Tags: hash, passwords

Here's a simple idea, based on some reading.

Server stores a hashed version of (plaintext + salt). This avoids passwords being seen, as long as the hash is hard to reverse.

When client attempts login, server sends it (salt,random), ie a constant salt and a newly generated random string.

Client sends back hash(hash(plaintext + salt) + random), ie client appends the salt, hashes, then appends the random, then hashes again.

Server checks that the hashed value is the same as it's own H(H(pwd+salt)+rnd).

I don't have much experience with this, so can I ask what the potential issues are? Also, what does one normally do with the salt? Can you really get away with using the same salt?

Comment: This question might be better suited for our sister site, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/. Unfortunately, it seems to be too old to migrate there.

Comment: I don't even remember writing it to be honest. Is it just me, or has traffic reduced a lot on SO? I've got a number of unanswered questions, which used to not happen.

Comment: @Carlos [It looks like traffic still growing](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com), not falling. More interesting would be the ratio of active question-askers to question-answers, but that's more tricky to dig up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme you are suggesting doesn't add any security to checking a password and simply adds complexity that using SSL for login doesn't. With SSL you can safely just transfer the plaintext password from the browser to the server, hash it with the salt, and then check against the stored hash. This eliminates the need for complex schemes. At this time, only nationstates can actually feasibly break SSL connections in a systemic way, although some really enterprising hackers have found some interesting vulnerabilities.

The scheme you are describing sounds very much like a Diffie-Hellman zero knowledge key exchange, which is much more secure than ssl as it never actually transfers the password after it is initially set up with the server. The problem with this kind of key exchange today, is that it must be written in Javascript on the client side and, as such, exposes the actual workings to every attacker that cares to look. The attacker could then just replace your Javascript with something else, or just tap into it to collect the initial passwords if you don't use SSL, so you are again just down to the security of the SSL connection from client to server with only a bunch of added complexity and failure points. There are ways to use ActiveX, Java, or other items to create browser plugins to handle all the key exchange stuff, but this again, adds a failure point for users that will be non-obvious, adds an extra step for the user that other sites don't require (installing the add-on or bookmarklet), and keeps you in development a lot longer for no real benefit.

Firefox has been working on implementing a Diffie-Hellman key exchange for passwords at the browser level, and this, if it ever takes off, will allow a lot of added security and make this kind of password scheme feasible.

Comment: I was mainly looking for whether I'd misunderstood something in my readings. It is indeed based on DH. I don't quite get how a hacker could get in just by modifying the client side. The idea was that it didn't matter that you knew how it worked.
I can imagine this type of system has some vulnerabilities, but I can't quite put my finger on what.
Regarding SSL, doesn't that start with some sort of key exchange? Or are you simply suggesting that the protocol already has this in place and with solutions for the well known vulnerabilities (and that for practical purposes, I might as well use that)?

Comment: @Carlos: The problem with authentication schemes where the client-side code is supplied over an insecure connection is that a MITM attacker could just modify the code to save the password _before_ it is hashed and send a copy of it to himself. (Of course, _any_ login form sent over HTTP without SSL has essentially the same vulnerability, which is why you _should_ use SSL. But once you use SSL, you have a secure channel, meaning that you might as well just send the password in plain.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: But the only place where the password isn't hashed is on the client machine. I don't see anything that isn't hashed going over the wire?

Comment: @Carlos: The _JS code_ that hashes the password is going over the wire, unencrypted, from the server to the client. An attacker who can intercept requests can change it to do whatever they want. (That's all assuming that you want to do this on a website. If you have a custom protocol with a dedicated client program, your suggestion becomes a lot more feasible. In that case you might want to take a look at SRP, though.)

Comment: Ah, so the problem is the JS can be abused, rather than that the password can be cracked?

Comment: What is SRP short for?

Comment: @Carlos: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol

Comment: SRP is a very useful protocol, however, when implemented in Javascript and sent without SSL, the attacker can simply inject Javascript to give him the plaintext password, or do whatever. Adding SSL provides protection for the password transfer and eliminates the need for SRP because the transfer is already secure. I too have tried implementations of SRP in Javascript and abandoned them because it was a lot of work with no tangable added benifit to the security.